# Not positive if the following solution is Case 3 of the Master Theorem

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics, recurrence, master-theorem

So I was wondering if the following recurrence would be considered to fall under case 3 of the Master Theorem: T(n)=4T(n/2) + 10000 - 5000sin(n).

So I've labeled my answer as the following...
**A** = 4, **B** = 2, **F(N)** = 10000 - 5000sin(n)

**n^k** = n^2

So when comparing F(n) to n^k we can see that f(n) **grows faster** than n^k, implying that this is case 3 of the master theorem. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since -1 ≤ sin(n) ≤ 1, 5000 ≤ f(n) ≤ 15000, which is O(1) since it never grows with input size.

This is case three because f(n) is constant time (`O(1)` == n<sup>0</sup>) which is asymptotically less than n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>4</sup>. So by the master theorem your recurrence relation T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).